# Move null items to the end of an array without delete in php

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array like :

```
`array (size=5)
0 => "" 
1 => ""
2 => "foo"
3 => ""
4 => "bar"`
```

i want to move all the empty items to the end, but keep them :
    `array (size=5)
    0 => "foo" 
    1 => "bar"
    2 => ""
    3 => ""
    4 => ""`

I tried to do `array_values(array_filter($myTab))` but result as :

```
`array (size=2)
 0 => "foo" 
 1 => "bar"
`
```

How to keep the empty item in php ?

Comment: Do you just want to retain the same size?

Comment: yes the i need the same size

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it in one line. I did make some to putt comments

```
$myTab = array (
"", 
"",
"foo",
"",
"bar");

// all not empty values
$a = array_filter($myTab);
// all empty values (rest in array)
$b = array_diff($myTab, $a);
// Full array
$new = array_merge($a, $b);
var_dump($new);
```

result

```
array(5) {
  [0]=>
  string(3) "foo"
  [1]=>
  string(3) "bar"
  [2]=>
  string(0) ""
  [3]=>
  string(0) ""
  [4]=>
  string(0) ""
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this if order doesn't matter:

```
rsort($myTabs);
```

Comment: It would be ok but i needed to keep the order